# How to synchronize on a File object in Android / Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrentmodification, synchronize

I have two `Fragments` and a `File` that contains a `JSON` representation of a `List<Competitor>`. In the first `Fragment` I create a `Competitor`. Then I send this `Competitor` to a background service via an `IntentService`. In the `IntentService` if open the `File` that contains the `List<Competitor>`, add the `Competitor`, then re-serialize / re-write the `File`.

After sending the `Competitor` to the `IntentService`, I send the user to the next `Fragment` (while the background service is writing the file). The problem is that the next screen looks for the same `File` and attempts to open it, and parse it into a `List<Competitor>` for use in a `RecyclerView`. However, if the background service is still writing the `File`, I will end up with a `concurrentModificationException`. This hasn't happened because the `File` write is quick but I want to prevent the possibility.

I was thinking I could `synchronize` on the `File` in the two different methods (write and read). I don't know if this is the right way to use `synchronize`. Below is what I'm thinking:

**The write method**

```
 public static void writeMasterCompetitorsFile(Context context, List<Competitor> competitors) {

        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), MASTER_COMP_FILE);

        synchronized (file) {
            String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(competitors);

            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
                writer.write(jsonString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

**The read method**

public static List getMasterCompetitorsList(Context context) {

```
List<Competitor> list = new ArrayList<>();
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), MASTER_COMP_FILE);

synchronized (file) {
    if (file.exists()) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String compList = reader.readLine();
            Type competitorListType = new TypeToken<List<Competitor>>() {
            }.getType();
            list = new Gson().fromJson(compList, competitorListType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        writeMasterCompetitorsFile(context, list);
    }
}
```

`Android Studio` is telling me that I shouldn't `synchronize` on a local variable. Do I have the right idea?

Comment: You should probably use a database instead.

Comment: Probably true. This project was originally written to use Json and files. I may eventually change it over to use a database, but I would first like to understand the concept of synchronization. It was not originally my idea to use files.

Comment: When using Java synchronization, you need to synchronize on the same Java object.  If two different methods use "new File(...)", they will not be the same object and the synchronization will not work as you intend.  A quick and dirty way to get what you want would be to synchronize on some public static Object that both methods have access to. Since both methods are static, this would not be too difficult. You could literally declare public static Object monitor = new Object(); and then use synchronized(monitor) {...}.

Comment: @GregMoens how would you associate the File with the Object? Like this: public static Object file = new File(...);  And this can be done on what ever method is called first? Then synchronize(file) ?

Comment: @Patric see my answer for a possible way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using a static object to synchronize.

```
public static final Object monitor = new Object();

public static void writeMasterCompetitorsFile(Context context, List<Competitor> competitors) {

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), MASTER_COMP_FILE);

    synchronized (monitor) {
        String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(competitors);

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            writer.write(jsonString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public static List getMasterCompetitorsList(Context context) {
    List<Competitor> list = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), MASTER_COMP_FILE);

    synchronized (monitor) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                String compList = reader.readLine();
                Type competitorListType = new TypeToken<List<Competitor>>() {
                }.getType();
                list = new Gson().fromJson(compList, competitorListType);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            writeMasterCompetitorsFile(context, list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I get it. Thank you. I have only seen the scenario where methods are synchronized. Now I understand the concept of the lock. :)